# String matrix input output

Tags: c, string, matrix

I want to make a matrix of strings in C Programming language 
this is my code

```
void main()
{
    char Data[10][3][20];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            Data[i][j]="aa";
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {

            printf("%s",Data[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Done");
    scanf("%d",&i);
}
```

the error am having is : `assignment to expression with array type`
please explain to me what am doing wrong because this is a prototype am trying to use in my original code that is to make a data base of "username,Password,level"

thank you inadvance.

Comment: And what have you done? Please provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: `Data[i][j]` is an *array*. You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. Read about [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: And for future reference, *please* [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what is your que basically ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I used strcopy and It didn't work 
and I reformed My question thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data[i][j]` is an array. You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. use `strcpy()`. more details at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main() {
    char Data[10][3][20];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
            strcpy(Data[i][j], "aa"); //use strcpy for copy values 
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        for (j=0;j<3;j++) {    
            printf("%s ",Data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Done");
    scanf("%d",&i); //why this scanf here ??
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @AmirBouker if this fix your error, don't forget to +1 it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of `char` and you cannot assign (a pointer) to it. This is why you are getting the error `assignment to expression with array type`.

You can copy the string to the array elements though. Try using `strcpy` instead of the below assignment in your code:

```
Data[i][j]="aa";
```